# SWT Notification animated box (a.k.a toaster) needed

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, desktop, desktop-application

In a Java project (SWT desktop app), I want to inform the user about events through animated notification box (actually, it's not required to be animated). Something like MSN or any other IM client.

There is [JToaster](http://jtoaster.sourceforge.net/) for Swing, but I wonder if there isn't any other implementation based on SWT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MyLyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn) plugin for Eclipse does this. Since it's open source, maybe you can check the MyLyn code to see how it's done there?

Comment: I started a Github repository to expose MyLyn-notifications to non-Eclipse-applications: https://github.com/ifischer/MylynNotifier. Its currently just a proof of concept. Contributions welcome (don't know when I find some time to extend it).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create SWT-based System notifications, this is the best resource to start with:

http://hexapixel.com/2009/06/30/creating-a-notification-popup-widget

The author creates real System notifications which are stackable and fade out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [BallonWindow from Novocode](http://www.novocode.com/swt/), it does something similar to what you need, without delving deep into an open source project.  It is not animated, but it does show a notification as a separate window with an irregular background.

I have a [blog post](http://www.jroller.com/ortegon/entry/custom_tooltip_using_eclipse_3) that explains its usage.